# How axiom of substitution implies unique function for ordinals in Halmos book?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm studying set theory using Halmos's book. I'm stopping at the chapter 19 about ordinal numbers.

I have 2 questions please:

1. Is the axiom of substitution necessary in the definition of ordinal number ? (provided that Halmos introduced axiom of substitution before giving definition of ordinal number)
2. How to use the axiom of substitution to prove that there exists a unique function $F$ on $\omega$ such that $F(0) = \omega$ and $F(n^+) = (F(n))^+$ for each natural number $n$.

Thank you very much for your help!

*-------------- Below is the context in the book --------------*

In his exposition, at first, the author starts with definition of $\omega$-successor function:

> Let us say that a function $f$ whose domain is the set of strict predecessors of some natural number $n$ (in other words, dom$f$ = $n$) is an $\omega$-successor function iff(0) = $\omega$ (provided that $n \neq 0$, so that $0 \lt n$), and $f(m^+) = (f(m))^+$ whenever $m^+ < n$. Here $\omega$ is the set of all natural numbers.

Then he states the axiom of substitution:

> **Axiom of substitution:** If $S(a, b)$ is a sentence such that for each $a$ in a
> set $A$ the set {$b:S(a, b)$}  can be formed, then there exists a function $F$ with
> domain $A$ such that $F(a) =$  {$b: S(a, b)$} for each $a \in A$

Then he gives the definition of ordinal number:

> An ordinal number is defined as a well ordered set $\alpha$ such that $s(t) = t$ for all $t \in  \alpha$. Note that here $s(t)$ is the initial segment {$ x \in \alpha: x \lt t$}.

Finally, he said that:

> The axiom of substitution implies easily that there exists a unique function $F$ on $\omega$ such that $F(0) = \omega$ and $F(n^+) = (F(n))^+$ for each natural number $n$.

Comment: Please note that $\omega$ `\omega`  is different from $w$. ( I have submitted a correction so threre's no more trouble here.)

Comment: Besides, $\xi$ is `\xi`. Better be faithful (for ease of searching) if the author represents ordinals by Greek letters, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) is a nice place to look them (and much more) up.

Answer (score 0):

Q.1: you may want to have a look at the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Applications)

Q.2: you may want to reread the second paragraph of the section, where Halmos says explicitly:

> Let $S(n, x)$ be the sentence that says  "$n$ is a natural number and $x$ belongs to the range of the $\omega$ -successor function with domain $n$."

So the sentence can be formed for $\omega$, the hypothesis of axiom of substitution is satisfied, so by the axiom there exists a unique function $F$ on $\omega$ etc., no further proof is needed.

**To the comment:**

I don’t think your problem is with the application of axiom of substitution, since a short comparison will ensure you that the axiom’s hypothesis is indeed satisfied:

> **Axiom of substitution**: $S(a, b)$ is a sentence...
>
> **The definition of $F$**: $S(n, x)$ *is* a sentence...
>
> **Axiom of substitution**: ...such that for each $a$ in a set $A$ the set {$b:S(a, b)$}  can be formed.
>
> **The definition of $F$**: The author himself says «[w]e know that for each natural number $n$ *we are permitted to form the set* ».

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but I think it isn't satisfactory. The quoted statement from Halmos and Axiom of substitution implies that there exist a function $F$ with domain $\omega$ such that: $F(n) =$ {$x : S(n,x)$}. Here the set {$x:S(n,x)$} contains all the elements in range of $\omega$-successor function with domain $n$. Meanwhile, the unique function $F$ in question is the function where the value of each $F(n)$ is a "number" (i.e. $F(0) = \omega$ and $F(n^+) = (F(n))^+$)
In other words, the function $F$ stated in axiom of substitution is not the same as the function $F$ in my question.

Comment: I guess you are bothered by the apparent difference between a «domain» and a «number», which is unnecessary, on the one hand the axiom of substitution doesn’t require $a$ to be just an element (indeed, since we are dealing with set theory $a$ is certainly a set), on the other hand the function $F$ on $\omega$ *is* what you get when you *have* at hand «all» the distinct ranges of the functions on $n \in \omega$: you simply make a union, recall that after all we proceed by making unions in ordinal numbers.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Put another way: by definition of ordinal numbers, sending $s(n)$ to $f(s(n))$ (i.e. $s(\omega+n)$) *is* sending $n$ to $\omega+n$.

Comment: No, excuse me, it’s actually quite tricky to talk about initial segments of $\omega$ in the image $f(n)$ for any $n \in \omega$, so just take my first comment, bear in mind that we are interested in being able to deriving transfinite ordinals from any $n \in omega$, but $\omega$ can be viewed not only as the set of all $n$’s but also -which is the same thing- as the union of all initial segments of all  $n \in \omega$.

Comment: Please check out my edits.